# Did Sisko violate Starfleet regulations or Federation laws when he fired a torpedo to devastate a planet's atmosphere & force it's occupants to flee?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

DS9 "For The Uniform":

> SISKO: Major, I want you to send the following message on all Maquis
>   frequencies. To all the members of the Maquis resistance. This is
>   Captain Sisko of the USS Defiant. In response to the Maquis's use of
>   biogenic weapons in their recent attacks, I am about to take the
>   following action. In exactly one hour, **I will detonate two quantum
>   torpedoes that will scatter trilithium resin in the atmosphere of
>   Solosos Three. I thereby will make the planet uninhabitable to all
>   human life for the next fifty years.** I suggest evacuation plans
>   begin immediately. What are you waiting for, people? Carry out your
>   orders.

When Sisko makes this order he gets dissenting looks for everyone on the bridge and everyone freezes. That's why He yells at them "What are you waiting for people, carry out your orders."

> (Later, orbiting Solosos Three.)
>
> KIRA: Incoming message. It's Eddington.
>
> EDDINGTON: (hologram) What are you really up to, Javert? Do you expect
>   me to believe that a decorated Starfleet officer, **the pride of the
>   service, is going to poison an entire planet?**

This is a very good question that Eddington asks Sisko. I've never heard of a Starfleet officer acting this way in an official matter.

> SISKO: That's exactly what I'm going to do.
>
> EDDINGTON: You're bluffing.
>
> SISKO: Am I? **Commander, launch torpedoes. Commander, I said launch
>   torpedoes!**

The reason he repeated himself is that Worf looked at Sisko like he was crazy and didn't fire them at first.

> WORF: Aye, sir.  (Two lights impact the atmosphere, and it starts
>   turning yellow.)
>
> KIRA: The trilithium resin is dissipating throughout the biosphere.
>   The Maquis are scrambling their transport ships. They're starting to
>   evacuate.
>
> EDDINGTON: Do you realise what you've done?
>
> SISKO: I've only just begun. **I'm going to eliminate every Maquis
>   colony in the DMZ.**
>
> EDDINGTON: You're talking about **turning hundreds of thousands of
>   people into homeless refugees.**

Eddington frames the gravity of Sisko's actions and what Sisko plans to do. It would appear that if this is a viable option the Federation would have considered it.

> SISKO: That's right. When you attacked the Malinche you proved one
>   thing, **that the Maquis have become an intolerable threat to the
>   security of the Federation**, and I am going intend to eliminate that
>   threat.

Is that reason enough to take the action Sisko took.

> EDDINGTON: But think about those people you saw in the caves, huddled
>   and starving. They didn't attack the Malinche.
>
> SISKO: You should have thought about that before you attacked a
>   Federation starship.  (Sisko turns his back on the Eddington hologram)
>
> SISKO: Helm, lay in a course for Tracken Two, warp six. Commander,
>   prepare two more torpedoes.
>
> NOG: Engine Room, bridge. Warp six.
>
> DAX: Set course zero five zero mark one seven nine.
>
> WORF: Unlock safeties on torpedoes three and four.
>
> EDDINGTON: Can't you see what's happening to you? You're going against
>   everything you claim to believe in, and for what? **To satisfy a
>   personal vendetta?**
>
> SISKO: **You betrayed your uniform**!
>
> EDDINGTON: **And you're betraying yours right now!** The sad part is, you
>   don't even realise it. I feel sorry for you, Captain. This obsession
>   with me, look what it's cost you.

This was clearly a personal vendetta. They weren't hunting the Maquis like this before or after. The Federation wouldn't shoot at human colonies destroying them or worse yet entire planets. Clearly that was unacceptable behavior or the Federation would have implemented that strategy from the get go and evacuated all the humans out of the Demilitarized zone and back to Federation space.

> SISKO: Major, shut that thing off! Commander Worf, prepare to launch
>   torpedoes!
>
> EDDINGTON: Wait! **If you call off your attack I'll turn over all our
>   biogenic weapons.**
>
> SISKO: **Not enough.**
>
> EDDINGTON: All right, Javert. **I'll give you what you want. Me.**

So it wasn't about the attacks or the Maquis, it was simply to bring Eddington back, who by the way committed no crime other then espionage to a non-enemy. It wasn't like Eddington was working for an enemy. Remember the Federation was not at war with the Maquis and the Maquis were not at war with the Federation.

> DAX: Benjamin, I'm curious. Your plan to poison the Maquis planets.
>   **You didn't clear it with Starfleet first, did you**.
>
> SISKO: I knew I'd forgotten to do something.
>
> DAX: Big gamble.
>
> SISKO: That's what it takes to be a good villain.

Further he didn't clear it with Starfleet. And he was ordered earlier in the episode to not pursue Eddington, and was taken off the assignment.

Think about how hard it was for Picard to violate the prime directive to save people. He'd never do something so selfish. Even Worf who is a warrior and loves battle was shocked and at first hesitated to obey orders.

I've never heard of Starfleet firing at civilian targets. I've also never heard of Starfleet firing at a different target other than the one who has offended. This sort of strategy is something I would expect from the Romulans, Cardassians, Borg, Dominion, etc. not from Starfleet.

So my question is did Sisko's actions of firing at a planet inhabited by human colonists,  for the purpose of making it uninhabitable, under the above scenario, violate Starfleet regulations or any Federation laws? If so is it a punishable offense. And if it is what was his punishment?

Comment: I would imagine that it would be against both regulations and the law. However, Sisko obviously was not punished for his actions. That inconsistency is most likely just the writers sacrificing realism for good drama.

Comment: @Alarion but doesn't it seem like this was just too much? Kind of like Bashir memory wiping Kurn? I never felt this way watching TNG, TOS, or Voyager. Sometimes I feel like Sisko and the rest of DS9 feel like they can do whatever they want because of there proximity to the worm hole and their distance from the rest of Starfleet/Federation. I just can't imagine any other Starfleet officer acting this way unless they are just plain evil and acting out of character. I've never seen an episode quite like this one.

Comment: Just to highlight: spying for a "non-enemy" is still spying. And there's a very famous real-world example of that right now: Edward Snowden. So, Starfleet could still consider his actions to be treasonous.

Comment: From memory alpha: Eddington triggers a cascade virus, disabling all of the Defiant's computer systems, leaving it effectively dead in space. This virus was planted by Eddington before he left Starfleet, further highlighting the depth of his betrayal. Also on DS9. Eddington wasn't just a low level analyst, he was Chief of Starfleet Security. That's like a 4 star general turning coat

Comment: Also the Maquis stole bio weapons, and Sisko's weapon only affected humans, not cardassians, and no humans should be in the dmz anyway. Its less a scorched earth policy than it was a targeted attack on an enemy stronghold.

Comment: @Ellesedil I have no problem with what Snowden did. I have a problem with what the government was doing. He pointed out, publicly I might add, that the government was violating it's own laws. But that aside. Let's say it is synonymous. Snowden made whatever he made public. The Maquis didn't do anything like that. They did steal some Federation technology. It was farming equipment, not weapons. The Maquis was simply a resistance movement trying to deal with the Cardassians not holding up their end of a treaty. People defending their homes is hardly an offense. Destroying a planet is, right?

Comment: @cde but he didn't sabotage the Defiant. The Defiant was the aggressor. The Defiant attacked his ship. His response was to set off the virus. That virus would have never been triggered had the Defiant not attacked him. In addition, he didn't kill Sisko at the beginning. He didn't kill Sisko when the Defiant was helpless. He didn't destroy the other Federation vessel that attacked him, he simply disabled it and left it adrift. Those are hardly the actions of an enemy.

Comment: We know (at least from the TNG Insurrection movie) that (post-Roddenberry) Star Fleet/Federation are fully capable of turning a blind eye towards crimes (as long as they profit from it and have plausible deniability) - Sisko was probably banking on that. Or it might be that the constitutional idea that a crime against another criminal is still a crime has fallen out of favor (I've seen it happen, not just on SciFi TV shows).

Comment: Rendering planets in a DMZ uninhabitable to one species doesn't seem like a crime. Especially when the Maquis is essentially provoking a Federation/Cardassian war.

Comment: @cde what bio weapons did they steal? I thought they purchased two relatively inexpensive and not-controlled chemicals and created the bio weapons. Also both the Cardassians and the Federation have planets in the DMZ. On the Federation side of the DMZ the Cardassian colonies were treated fairly, on the Cardassian side the human colonies were not. Remember the earlier episode where they uncover all of it & that the Obsidian order has ships in the DMZ, etc. After the attack on the founders homeworld & the Klingon assault the Cardassians were weakened so couldn't keep up their aggression as much

Comment: Basically, read RDM's comment on Sisko's actions. Basically, he pulled a Kirk cowboy diplomacy maneuver.http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/For_the_Uniform_(episode)#Reception

Comment: @EikePierstorff maybe you're on to something. You think it's a post Roddenberry thing. Might be... I never considered that. Part of what made Picard, Kirk, Janeway, etc. great was the constant struggle to balance the prime directive, crossing the line, when to fight, when to help defenseless people, etc. The struggle in the characters is what makes Star Trek great. We all love Data, Odo, Spock, the Voyager Doctor, 7 of 9, even Quark, b/c of the struggle. Without the rules, regualtions, etc., once it becomes a free for all, Star Trek loses it's mission and it's coherence.

Comment: @cde that's absolute blasphemy. Kirk would never do such a thing. Kirk who had every reason to hate Klingons was responsible for the Khitomer accords going through. Kirk would never jeopardize a people like that. This what not cowboy diplomacy. There was nothing diplomatic about it. It was cruel.

Comment: Sisko didn't have a vendetta, he went to such measures because he couldn't have caught Eddington otherwise. He even says so in the episode. That to catch him, he needed to play into his idea that he's the hero and Sisko's the villain. Eddington was the one obsessed.

Comment: This is an excellent question, something that I had always wondered about.  Reading your quotes made me realize something new - Sisko's actions never endangered any lives.  The way it's described, it sounds like the "poison" was something that killed over the course of days, not minutes.  Even when Eddington made his appeal, it was about making the inhabitants homeless refugees, not actively harming them.  So even calling his action an "attack" is debatable, which is probably why he could get away with it.

Comment: @MartianInvader I would add that even in war there are many hostile acts designed to destroy lives even if they don't directly kill -- cutting off supply routes, blockades, "resettling". Just because no one dies right away doesn't mean the intent for harm wasn't there. I think that because Sisko *knowingly* did this against StarFleet code and procedure, he acted with the intent to cause harm knowing it was wrong. So no matter why he acted that way, that he knowingly harmed people at all indicates his abandonment of his principles and uniform. I think BOTH Sisko and Eddington were obsessed.

Comment: Did you really not notice all the other detail you Posted mattered far less than:

… SISKO: I knew I'd forgotten to do something.

To whom does that not make obvious that he was bluffing, and nothing else matters?

Comment: I suggest most of those details merely confuse the issue, which should be whether Sisko had, or would have got had he sought it, permission.

What seems to matter is whether he cleared what with Starfleet… and yes, whether he was ordered to not pursue Eddington, and taken off the assignment.

Various reference- and fan-sites list directives specifically designed to control the wiping out of planets…

Answer (score 18):

Here are some regulations which pertain to this situation:

> - *Starfleet Charter Articles* - Article 14, Section 31: The exact language has never been cited, but certain lines in this section **permitted the use of "extraordinary measures" in times of dire emergency**. (ENT: "Divergence")
> - General Order 24: **An order to destroy all life on an entire planet**. 
>     (TOS: "Whom Gods Destroy", "A Taste of Armageddon")
> - Special Order 66715: Federation order that stated: "[Starfleet has] the authority to neutralize security threats to Deep Space 9 **by any means necessary**". (DS9: "Inquisition")

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_General_Orders_and_Regulations))

Now, between these three orders, it could possibly be construed that Sisko was acting *within* regulations.  The use of biogenic weapons could be considered to be a dire emergency, and the Maquis having access to these could also be considered a threat to DS9 (considering its proximity to Bajor).  The fact a general order exists to destroy all life on an entire planet also indicates that under certain circumstances it would be acceptable to destroy the life-sustaining properties of a planet.  So, by extension, to make a planet toxic for a particular life form would also be acceptable under certain circumstances.

Another interesting (but non-canon) regulation I found:

> - Regulation 21, Section 6, Paragraph 4: "Federation security supersedes the rights and privileges of Federation citizens." (New Worlds, New Civilizations short story: "An Enigma Wrapped in a Puzzle")

[(Source)](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_General_Orders_and_Regulations)

It could also be argued that any rights the Maquis had were superseded by Sisko's actions to remove threats to the Federation that the Maquis' weapon posed.

Another important order is below:

> - Starfleet Order 2: Starfleet regulation **against the taking of intelligent life**. (TAS: "One of Our Planets Is Missing")

Now, considering the Maquis had the capacity to evacuate a planet, by destroying the suitability of a planet for a certain life form Sisko possibly wouldn't be held responsible for this, as the Maquis could prevent this from occurring.

Hence, based on this research it would seem that Sisko could argue his way out of violating any regulations or laws **that we know of**; there are plenty of regulations we simply don't know about (see [this Memory Alpha article](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_law); there's still lots we don't know about)

Comment: Well, they didn't destroy the life sustaining abilities of the planet. They just made it toxic to humans, for 50 years, a minor inconvenience. It was still good to go for other species (mainly the cardassians). The maquis weapon did the same. Poisoned it to Cardassians, fine for humans. Nothing affecting vegetable or animal life either.

Comment: Fair enough and good post, but my question is whether he violated Starfleet regulations, not whether an excuse could be made to justify his actions. Aren't there treaties or laws against the Federation using chemical weapons? Is a Starfleet officer allowed to threaten and attack unrelated civilian targets to get a military one to stand down? I can't think of another example of this. Imagine Picard giving that order to Worf, ludicrous, right? I'll consider your answer though. +1

Comment: Article 14, section 31 does not seem to apply, where's the emergency? Sisko was under no orders to do what he did, so I don't think general order 24 would apply. In fact he was ordered not to go after Eddington. Even Dax points out at the end that he didn't clear any of it with Starfleet which she felt was a problem or she wouldn't have asked the question. Special order 66715 again, what was the threat to DS9. He never attacked anything Starfleet or Federation, he only defended. In addition DS9 held off an entire Klingon fleet, I think it can handle a couple Maquis ships.

Comment: @JMFB the point in my post is that, considering the mentioned regulations, it could be argued that he didn't violate any regulations at all, thereby addressing your question directly.  And no, I couldn't find any direct regulations against Starfleet/Federation using chemical weapons (so far anyway - I'll keep looking!)

Comment: @JMFB; if Starfleet hadn't done something about the Maquis, it could have posed a very real threat against DS9 - the Cardassians wouldn't have been impressed!  The emergency could have been avoiding a diplomatic nightmare with the Cardassians (although I'm not sure about this - I'm not 100% familiar with DS9 I admit)

Comment: @JMFB - his justification seems to be that the Maquis attacked a Federation starship, which is something that they had never really done before.

Comment: Apologies for necro-ing this but having seen *For the Uniform* again recently I think there is an argument that Special Order 66715 **does** apply here. Eddington had placed more malware similar to the cascade virus that disabled the *Defiant* in the systems of DS9 itself - and while Odo was working to find and remove them he admitted he couldn't be sure he'd found them all. Had Eddington activated such a virus on the station it would have most definitely been threatened - and with it the whole Alpha Quadrant.

Comment: "Federation security supersedes the rights and privileges of Federation citizens." Just wow. Section 31 makes so much more sense now...

Comment: @RoboBear That's a non-canon regulation.  Of course, the Marqui were *no longer Federation Citizens* either