# Does Cpt. Sisko ever face consequences for his actions in "For the Uniform"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-eu

In Deep Space Nine's episode "*For the Uniform*", Sisko takes following action: he detonates two torpedos loaded with trilithium resin in the atmosphere of a Maqui planet, making the planet uninhabitable to humans for more or less 50 years, and he never clears it with Starfleet Command.

Does he ever face any kind of consequences for this drastic action?

All levels of canon are welcome, books, games, TV show, etc.

Comment: It's not even sure if he violated any regulations, according to [Question 93049](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93049/did-sisko-violate-starfleet-regulations-or-federation-laws-when-he-fired-a-torpe)

Comment: @dutop this smells very dupey to me

Comment: @dutop I've read that question - him breaking regulations is questionable IMHO - many of these rules were up for interpretation, or were very vague. It is even doubtful is catching Eddington required such measures - this was for Starfleet Command to decide, and he didn't consult them beforehand so we basicly don't know if he broke the rules or not (we have Proportionality laws, preventing us from nuking small hostile countries). This was a drastic actions and consequences are possible in both cases (broke rules or not). My question is closely tied to the linked question, but it's not a dupe

Comment: The incident isn't mentioned again. The next time we see Sisko, he's in his office getting on with some paperwork.

Comment: @Richard On the show, true, but there are plenty of books and non-TV show material, with which I am not familiar. That's why I'm asking

Comment: @Petersaber - There's a very brief reference in [one of the non-canon novels](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Genesis_Wave). Admiral Nechayev refers to his tactics as "*perhaps [not] the best way to handle the situation, but it worked.”*. There's no mention of punishment/reward for Sisko.

Comment: @Richard if nobody else finds any other mention, that might as well be an answer to be accepted

Comment: @Petersaber: That answer would be more authoritative if you mentioned you were ok with published non-canon sources in your question.

Comment: @Ellesedil Good point! I'll add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Main canon (TV / Films).

There appear to be no short- or long-term consequences for Sisko.

**Short term.** The very next episode we see Sisko in his office quite unconcernedly getting on with paperwork. No mention is made of any censure or a trip to Earth to explain his actions.

**Long Term.** Over the following year Sisko receives two substantial promotions; acting as the Federation's military liaison with the Klingons and coordinating Federation war efforts against the Dominion in his Sector. It's pretty clear that his career trajectory hasn't been harmed.

### EU Canon

There's an extremely brief mention of Solosos III in the EU novel ['The Genesis Wave, Book III'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743463838). It would appear the Sisko's actions, while considered somewhat inelegant, were nonetheless regarded as legitimate and proportionate.

> Nechayev nodded sagely. “Regimol just sent word that he’s wracked his
>   brain, and he thinks that could be it. As you must know, there was a
>   Maquis colony there, led by a Starfleet officer named Michael
>   Eddington. **A Starfleet effort to capture him made the planet
>   unlivable. It wasn’t perhaps the best way to handle the situation, but
>   it worked.”**
>
> Teska nodded. “Yes, firing quantum torpedoes with trilithium resin
>   into the atmosphere was effective in making the planet unlivable.”
>
> “I meant that Eddington surrendered,” said the admiral with a scowl.
>   “Regimol says that both the Bajorans and the Maquis revere Solosos III
>   as the site of the Maquis’s most noble defeat, because **we had to
>   destroy the planet to save it. When you root for the underdog, that’s
>   the kind of battle you appreciate, I guess.** I wasn’t involved, but
>   it was a turning point. Eddington was a charismatic leader.”

Comment: Key point to take away from DSN: while Sisko can bend and break the rules as he wants without repercussion, Worf cannot.

Comment: @Xantec - Precisely. I think it's because Sisko has the goods on Admiral Leyton

Comment: Picard should ask him for pointers.

Comment: Sisko's relationships with senior officers definitely seems to come in handy. Even when junior officers, like Kira, complain about Ben to SF Command, the admirals (more than one) all seem to always back Sisko. I get the impression Sisko is very well liked, perhaps one of the reasons he was placed at DS9 in the first place.